# Incrementing a value in Flask with peewee

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, peewee

I have been making an application with Flask and Peewee and I am trying to increment a value by one in the database using the **update()** function.

Here is the problem:

```
models.User.update(
        likes+=1
        ).execute()
```

This is not working and I simply get the error:

```
  File "app.py", line 171
   love+=1
     ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
User.update(likes=User.likes+1).execute()
```

See [Atomic Updates](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#atomic-updates) for details.